# Some Files Crunching Failed when i am importing project in android Studio from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':myHealthyBreakfast:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

This scenario happened when I'm importing my project in android studio . Here the files that are crunching might be 9 patch files that I'm using in eclipse .

What is the best solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle(Project file) downgrading the version of classpath will definitely solve this issue .

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

To

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```